# ¿Cómo insertar datos a una tabla en Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Django. Donde tengo un modelo llamado `usuarios` y otro `eventos`. Uno de los campos del modelo `eventos` se llama `participantes` que es del tipo `ManyToManyField`.

**models.py** de `eventos`:

```
class Eventos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=True)
    fecha_evento = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    participantes = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario)
```

Hasta ahora nada raro, tengo el listar de todos los registros de `eventos` en **views.py**.

```
class ListarEvents(ListView):
    template_name = 'eventos/listar_eventos.html'
    model = Eventos
    context_object_name = 'eventos'
```

Los eventos los renderizo en el archivo **listar_eventos.html**

```
{% for e in eventos  %}
                <main style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="album py-5 bg-body-tertiary">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card shadow-sm">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text">{{e.descripcion}}</p>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Participar</button>
                                </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
{% endfor %}
```

Ahora viene lo que quiero hacer.
Tengo un template llamado `eventos_usuarios.html` en donde renderizo todos los registros de la tabla `participantes`.

Lo que quiero hacer y no sé cómo, es que cuando el usuario logueado haga click en el boton de **participar** de los eventos, se agregue automaticamente en la tabla de `participar` el `id` del **evento**, y el `id` del **usuario** logueado.

Ya logré renderizar todos los eventos de la tabla `participantes`.

Listar los eventos del usuario que desea participar **views.py**.

```
class ListarEventosUsuario(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'eventos/eventos_usuarios.html'
    model = Eventos
    context_object_name = 'eventos_usuarios'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(participantes=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Codigo de **eventos_usuarios.html**

```
{% for evento in eventos_usuarios  %}
            <main style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
                <div class="album py-5 bg-body-tertiary">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">{{evento.descripcion}}</p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Dejar de participar</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </main>
{% endfor %}
```

Pero no puedo darle funcionalidad al botón `participar`.
**AYUDA**

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar funcionalidad al botón "Participar" y permitir que el usuario logueado se agregue automáticamente como participante del evento, puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Agrega una URL y una vista para manejar la acción de participar en un evento:

En el archivo `urls.py` de tu proyecto, agrega una URL que corresponda a la vista que manejará la acción de participar en un evento. Por ejemplo:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import participar_evento

urlpatterns = [
    # Otras URLs
    path('participar/<int:evento_id>/', participar_evento, name='participar_evento'),
]
```

2. Crea la vista `participar_evento` en tu archivo `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def participar_evento(request, evento_id):
    evento = get_object_or_404(Eventos, id=evento_id)
    evento.participantes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('eventos_usuarios')
```

En este ejemplo, utilizamos el decorador `login_required` para asegurarnos de que el usuario esté autenticado antes de realizar la acción de participar en un evento. Luego, obtenemos el evento correspondiente utilizando `get_object_or_404`, agregamos al usuario actual a la lista de participantes del evento y redirigimos al usuario a la página de eventos del usuario.

3. Actualiza el botón "Participar" en tu plantilla `listar_eventos.html`:

```html
{% for e in eventos %}
    <main style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
        <div class="album py-5 bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text">{{ e.descripcion }}</p>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a href="{% url 'participar_evento' evento_id=e.id %}"
                                           class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Participar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endfor %}
```

Aquí utilizamos la etiqueta de anclaje `<a>` en lugar de un botón `<button>`. Configuramos el atributo `href` para que apunte a la URL de la vista `participar_evento`, pasando el ID del evento como parámetro en la URL.

Con estos cambios, cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón "Participar", se llamará a la vista `participar_evento`, se agregará el usuario actual como participante del evento correspondiente y se redirigirá al usuario a la página de eventos del usuario (`eventos_usuarios.html`).

Comment: No uses ChatGPT para [responder preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). El usuario vino a Stackoverflow apra que un humano lo ayude con su problema, si hubiera querido usar ChatGPT lo habría hecho por su cuenta